# Join query using the go-pg package

Tags: package, go-pg

In the go-pg package, the results corresponding to the query
"select d.datname, r.rolname from pg_database d join pg_roles r on d.datdba = r.oid where d.datname not in ('template0', 'template1')"
I want to get it, but it doesn't work. Please help.

In the go-pg package, the results corresponding to the query
"select d.datname, r.rolname from pg_database d join pg_roles r on d.datdba = r.oid where d.datname not in ('template0', 'template1')"
I want to get it, but it doesn't work. Please help. thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate on "but it doens't work"? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: var result []DatabaseRoleInfo
 err = db.Model(&result).
  ColumnExpr("d.datname AS datname, r.rolname AS rolname").
  Table("pg_database d").
  Join("JOIN pg_roles r ON d.datdba = r.oid").
  Where("d.datname NOT IN ('template0', 'template1')").
  Select()

Comment: That's a code snippet, not an explanation of the problem. What exactly is going wrong? Are you getting an error? The wrong results? Something else?

Comment: oh, "ERROR #42P01 relation "database_role_infos" does not exist" error occur

Comment: I need to get results corresponding to this query. Please help.

Comment: "select d.datname, r.rolname from pg_database d join pg_roles r on d.datdba = r.oid where d.datname not in ('template0', 'template1')"

Comment: Is that the exact query you're using? Because `database_role_infos` from the error message doesn't appear anywhere there...

Comment: Sorry, but please show me code without errors.